# How can I work with Chinese characters from a database?

Tags: database, delphi, unicode

I am facing problem capturing Chinese characters in a dataset.

In Delphi 2010 I have tried two kinds of components:

1. Delphi default
2. Developer Express components

As result, those components that do not link to the datasource are working fine, but those components *do* that link to the datasource have a problem. The Chinese characters have been converted into question marks, except in the TDBMemo. See the image below.

The dataset is a client-dataset with two fields:

1. Name - string
2. Description - Memo

What should I do in order to get it work?

[Reference Image http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9445/d2010unicodetestsimplif.gif](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9445/d2010unicodetestsimplif.gif)

```
type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
ClientDataSet1Name: TStringField;
ClientDataSet1Description: TMemoField;
DataSource1: TDataSource;
ClientDataSet2: TClientDataSet;
ClientDataSet2Name: TStringField;
ClientDataSet2Description: TMemoField;
DataSource2: TDataSource;
```

Comment: Do you use the ClientDataset standalone or do you retrieve the data for ClientDataset via a DatasetProvider? In the second case it is interessting to know from where the Provider retrieve the data. Perhaps it is a Database problem?

Comment: It is Standalone ClientDataset without linking to Databse yet.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 2010, `TStringField` and `TMemoField's` value property is of type `AnsiString`.  That is the reason why the Chinese characters doesn't show in the data aware controls.

Instead, you should declare the field type as `ftWideString` or `ftWideMemo` to create `TWideStringField` and `TWideMemoField` respectively.

Answer (score -1):

1) Im using ClientDataset standalone without any data provider.

2) We are expecting that the result should be same for TEdit and TDBEdit. Isn't it D2010 a Native Unicode ?

it is just a simple standalone ClientDataset as follow:

---

**type TForm1 = class(TForm)**

ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;

ClientDataSet1Name: TStringField;

ClientDataSet1Description: TMemoField;

DataSource1: TDataSource;

ClientDataSet2: TClientDataSet;

ClientDataSet2Name: TStringField;

ClientDataSet2Description: TMemoField;

DataSource2: TDataSource;

Comment: James, use the Add comment facility to respond to questions, or edit your original to add more info. Don't answer with a new answer as it is answering your own question.